Lie derivative and commutator of vector fields
I'm self-studying differential geometry. In many differential geometry textbooks (Lee's and Tu's for example). The formula for Lie derivative is given by
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_V U=[V,U],
\end{align}
where $V$ and $U$ are vector fields on a manifold. I haven't read the proof but as I understand, Lie derivative is a generalisation of directional derivative. So in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can write
\begin{align}
D_V U=[V,U].
\end{align}
Now let's consider the case in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $V=x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $U=y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. According to my calculations
\begin{align}
D_V U&=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\\
[V,U]&=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial y},
\end{align}
which are NOT the same so the formula $\mathcal{L}_V U=[V,U]$ cannot be correct. However, $D_U V=y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, so the correct formula might be $D_V U-D_U V=[V,U]$
for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{L}_V U-\mathcal{L}_U V=[V,U]$ for a manifold.
Where did I go wrong? I'm new to differential geometry so I must be misunderstanding something.

Lie derivative should not be viewed as a directional derivative.

So Lie derivative in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not directional derivative but the difference between directional derivatives (i.e. $\mathcal{L}^{\mathbb{R}^n}_V U=D_V U-D_U V$)? I wonder what the generalisation of directional derivative in a manifold is if it is not Lie derivative.

On a manifold, there is only the directional derivative of a function. A directional derivative of a vector field that satisfies the basic properties you want is called a connection or covariant derivative. There is no unique or best choice of a connection on a manifold. If, however, you assume the manifold is Riemannian, then there is a unique connection that  works best with the Riemannian metric. This is known as the Levi-Civita connection.

The directional derivative (on a manifold) with respect to a vector field $V$ I want to mention is the way to measure the rate a (scalar, vector, tensor,...) field changes at a given point  when we follow the vector field $V$. To me, the word "derivative" always meant the rate of change with respect to something. From what I learnt about Lie derivative, I was convinced that it kind of serves the purpose of directional derivative.  If Lie derivative is not what I thought then what is its interpretation? Does it have anything to do with "the rate of change"?

I've always found it difficult to understand the motivation behind the Lie derivative of one vector field to another. Wikipedia has the standard explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation.

It is differentiation along the flow of the vector field $V$. It depends on local data, not just a single direction.

@Ted Shifrin That's exactly how I think of Lie derivative. My question was does Lie derivative become directional derivative if we are working on $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of a general manifold?

And what I said answers that. As earlier comments have said, only when you are taking the Lie derivative of a function is this the case.

Thanks for your answers. Afer pondering for a while, I realised my problem was I misinterpreted the definition of Lie derivative. As Tu's book suggests, the reason directional derivative doesn't work on a general manifold is that we can't subtract 2 vectors in different tangent spaces. To fix that, we need to transform one to the tangent space of the other by using flow. I thought in $\mathbb{R}^n$, this process is just subtracting 2 arrow vectors, which turns out to be wrong.
